# URLs amigables - PHP

Tags: php, html, url

Es muy importante saber que las URLs amigables están para poder facilitar al usuario el poder 'memorizar' de cierta manera los enlaces.

Pero, ¿Cómo puedo cambiar esto?

> www.midominio.com.mx/clientes.php?id=8

Por esto:

> www.midominio.com.mx/clientes/pedrito

- ¿Podrían explicarme más detalladamente como hacerlo?
- ¿Es necesario el uso de .htaccess?
- Si es necesario, ¿Cómo creo un .htaccess en mi localhost?

Comment: Hola, es medio confusa tu pregunta quieres crear Urls amigables o en resumen que es lo que necesitas???

Comment: Más bien es teórica-practica jaja

Comment: ¿Podrías ser un poco más específico? Quizá con algún ejemplo o algo!

Comment: Para quienes votaron en negativo (al menos dos hasta ahora): deben indicar porqué el negativo; si la pregunta no es clara o correcta hay que indicar porqué para que el usuario la mejore. De otro modo la pregunta seguirá siendo de mala calidad (si es que ese es el problema).

Comment: La he modificado, espero ser claro esta vez. Saludos.

Comment: @Hoose Deberías crear mejor otra pregunta con las ediciones, Por que mientras esta pregunta este en **Espera** sera descartada para muchos.   Plantea-la nuevamente la pregunta?. Así podrás tener más respuesta y útil, con la edición que haz realizado la pregunta esta más clara.

Comment: @Hoose Está mucho más clara, pero podrías indicar a partir de las respuestas que recibiste, ¿qué es específicamente lo que estás preguntando? Por ejemplo, en ambas respuestas te muestran cómo convertir un enlace en parámetro GET a tu PHP... ¿qué es lo que te faltaría a partir de ahí?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para crear un archivo **.htaccess** debes crear un nuevo documento en blanco y guardar con la siguiente extensión el archivo `.htaccess`

Ahora para crear una **Urls** amigable ya dependería de tu proyecto.

Para comenzar, un ejemplo de una Urls amigable.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?id=$1
```

Explicación:

En un sitio web e-commerce todo producto tiene una descripción detallando características del producto.

Ahora en cada detalle de un producto se mostraría de esta manera:
**example.com/detalle.php?id=1**

En la Urls amigable se mostraría de esta manera: **example.com/iphone-s6-plus**

**Back-end en PHP**

El Back-End es el área que se dedica a la parte lógica de un sitio web, es el encargado de que todo funcione como debería, el back-end es la parte de atrás que de alguna manera no es visible para el usuario ya que no se trata de diseño, o elementos gráficos, se trata de programar las funciones que tendrá un sitio. El Back-End es la programación dura y pura, desde la programación de las funciones del sitio hasta bases de datos e incluso mas.

El Back-end trabaja todo el tiempo con lenguajes de programación, lenguajes que requieren de una lógica ya que esta área es también la encargada de optimizar recursos, de la seguridad de un sitio y demás. Cosas que el usuario no ve de primeras pero que existe código detrás que esta haciendo su trabajo.

Los lenguajes de programación que se utilizan en el Back-end en la actualidad son PHP, Javascript, Phyton y Ruby. Ademas de HTML y CSS, que aunque básico, también deben saber al menos un poco. Aquí me gustaría hablar de 2 cosas, primero que nada, yo he mencionado 4 lenguajes de programación, pero no son todos los que existen y no es obligatorio utilizar todos y cada uno de ellos, hay programadores back-end que solo saben algunos, no es necesario saber todos, depende de lo que se quiera programar y de las capacidades del lenguaje. Como segunda cosa que me gustaría comentar es que aunque el Back-End también debe saber de HTML y CSS, no es necesario saber a un nivel alto como lo haría un Front-End, es simplemente para poder crear una estructura básica en la que trabajar.

Las herramientas que se utilizan en el Back-end son editores de código, compiladores, algunos debuggeadores para revisar errores y seguridad, gestores de bases de datos y algunas otras cosas.

El flujo de trabajo de un back-end consiste en darle funciones a un sitio, por lo general el front-end hace un sitio estático, y el back-end después le da funciones y adapta el sistema programado a ese sitio web. Es por eso que las personas que se dedican al back-end también tienen que tener conocimientos al menos básicos de front-end. Para poder juntar las 2 partes en 1.

[Fuente](http://www.falconmasters.com/web-design/que-es-front-end-y-que-es-back-end/)

Comment: Solo para complementar la respuesta: las URLs amigables se pueden hacer desdel el backend, aunque no es necesario PHP, sino configurar un archivo .htaccess. En la respuesta se explica como crear el archivo y configurarlo para tener URLs amigables.

Comment: @Roimer Claro que se puede configurar el archivo .htaccess pero recuerda que este debe estar en la carpeta del proyecto en el directorio del sitio web para que funcione las Urls amigable. (Aunque no es necesario PHP) ??? Bueno el archivo **.htaccess** es de PHP. Pero para crear Urls amigable los archivo lo documentos no precisamente tiene que estar en php puedes acortar las urls sin extensión `.php` ` .html ` entre otros.

Comment: @J.Doe En el .htaccess, en la parte de `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?id=$1` Si tengo 5 detalles, ¿Tendría que escribir 5 RewriteRule con su respectivo id?

Comment: @Hoose no amigo si tienes 5 detalles o más con aquel codigo es suficiente para todos. Ahora si tienes otra pagina que no sea detalle hay si tienes que crear un nuevo rewriterule. Ejemplo `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ page.php?id=$1` solo cuando tengas una pagina diferente, un solo registro funcionara con todos los datos que tengas.

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un htaccess es tan simple como crear un archivo vacio con el nombre .htaccess. Los comandos que puedes crear dentro ya depende de tus necesidades, algo muy básico para hacer una url amigable podría ser:

```
# Activar RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on

# Reescribir la URL solicitada por el usuario
#   Entrada:  clientes/NOMBRE/
#   Salida: clientes.php?id=NOMBRE
RewriteRule ^clientes/(\w+)/?$ clientes.php?id=$1
```

Antes asegurate que tiene el módulo mod_rewrite activado en tu server, para ello create un archivo php que contenga esto dentro:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Cuando abras tu php te saldrá una ventana con todos los módulos instalados.