# Redireccion 301 .htaccess Con Parámetro (string) en la Variable (Ayuda)

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, redirección, get

Intento de manera ya desesperada:

Crear un tipo de `redirección 301`, a una página que se llama: "`categoria.php`"

Esta página, contiene un:

```
$url = $_GET['s'];
```

Se supone que al poner esta url: `www.miweb.com/prueba`

La variable `$url`, de la página `categoría.php`, debería contener "prueba"

-

Ahora mismo estoy probando con:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ categoria.php?s=$1 [QSA]
```

No me funciona, he probado mil y una forma más, y no consigo acertar.

¿Alguien podría por favor ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que todo lo que vaya a la ruta inicial, redirija al mismo script (categoria.php), con esto es suficiente:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./categoria.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Al escribir: miweb.com/prueba -> me da un error 500 :(

Comment: tienes el módulo "mod_rewrite" instalado?
Lamento no poder ayudarte mucho ahora, porque estoy de viaje, pero mira este enlache, aquí tienes una respuesta un poco más amplia que seguro te puede ayudar:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20786/urls-amigables-php